# How can I make cmd fullscreen?

Tags: windows

How can I make cmd fullscreen? pretty simple question (I think).

I only managed to make it big it enough that it fits almost all of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will make it full screen.  Press that key combo again to restore it to previous.

I've tested this and it definitely works as expected in Windows 10 Creators Update, but not in Windows 7.

Answer (score -1):

Double-click the title bar of the window.

Comment: This was the answer which I also was going to post. However it seems we are both wrong. Double-click the title bar make it a full sized window. the ALT-ENTER makes is really full screen,

Comment: Double clicking doesn't work either unless it is Windows 10.

Comment: @Hennes: Evidently that's not what the poster asked for, but normally a fullscreen application includes the frame for the simple reason that one can use the frame to undo it.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Tested in Windows 7 and Alt+Enter does not work either. In fact, fullscreen cmd of any kind *only* works in Windows 10.

Comment: Curiously I just had the opportunity and need to try Alt+Enter on Windows 7 and you are right, it doesn't work. I'm certain I've seen and used it on a previous version of Windows but my poor memory is giving me the sinking feeling that the last time I used a full screen command prompt was back in the days of Win 95/98... For now I'll specify my answer as only being known to work in Win10.

Comment: Also worked in Windows XP, 95, 98, ME, and I think Windows 3.1.  Side note: OS/2 used Alt-Home.  Did not work in Windows Vista using newer video driver model, nor Windows 10.  I'm happy to learn it got "fixed" again by Windows 10.  Although, it is different: In Windows 10, it is showing a scroll bar while in full screen, which I don't think happened in Windows XP and earlier.

Comment: Even proggies like fstoggle.exe don't work in Windows 7.  DOS programs, like MSD, can't load either, for the same reason.  It's something ro do with the video driver model or something.